# ASP.NET httpRedirect exactDestination for all pages except root

Tags: redirect, iis

I'm changing the primary domain for an IIS website, and I need to keep existing URLs working. At the same time I am changing the behaviour of the start page of this (the previous) domain. This domain has previously been accessible at its root level, but now I need the root page (default document) to redirect to a specific subdirectory.

In summary: I need to, while redirecting, keep the trailing path for all pages except for the default document (root). Example:

- `www.old.com/` -> `www.new.com/en`
- `www.old.com/en/page2.htm` -> `www.new.com/en/page2.htm`
- `www.old.com/en/page3.htm` -> `www.new.com/en/page3.htm`
- `www.old.com/page1.htm` -> `www.new.com/page1.htm`

I have this `web.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.new.com" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" exactDestination="false" />
    </system.webServer>
    <location path="Default.aspx">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.new.com/en" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" exactDestination="true" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

I have set the IIS setting **Default Document** to `Default.aspx`.

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the URL Rewrite Module in IIS instead:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Root request" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url="^$" />
                     <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.new.com/en" redirectType="Found" />
                 </rule>             
                 <rule name="Path request" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url="^(.*)$" />
                     <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.new.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
                 </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```